# Mirror a User across all accounts Win 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts, clone

I'm trying to setup a tablet image for cloning purposes using Acronis. I have finally setup an Acronis WinPE USB to clone the drive on the device with the image I want to distribute across our tablets.

The issue I'm having is that each new device is going to have a different autologin separate from the autologin setup on the cloned device. If I can make the settings standardized across all users so that the tiles, desktop shortcuts, and policies are the same, then it would alleviate having to do it each time I setup a new tablet for deployment.

Anybody have any idea on how I could go about accomplishing this?

I'm Running Win 8.1 x64 on a Lenovo Thinkpad 10 if that helps.

EDIT: To clarify I am on our domain with the devices, the issue is that each device needs a different autologin, which needs to have the same setup as the source device's autologin settings.

Comment: This normally would be done by a group policy.  Since you can't join Windows 8.1 Core to a domain, it means you have to modify the default user policy on the source machine, before you create the image.  Plently of documentation exist on how to modify the default user profile.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these devices are connected to our domain. But are not being added to our deployment software as we don't support Win 8.1 and do not have a package to push to the machine. Any way you could link me the documentation on modifying the profile correctly? I'm having trouble finding the right source to accomplish this task.

Comment: [First Result](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825135.aspx) when I searched for [*modify default user profile windows 8.1*](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=modify+default+user+profile+windows+8.1)

Comment: Would this affect a profile with Autologin setup through the registry? I think that might have been the issue with trying to google the issue.

Comment: So you configured the profile, to be the profile, that is automatically logged into it?  I was addressing how you can standardize all users, since you are not using the domain, to configure them.  You might want to clarify that fact, because your question as it stands, indicates your using Windows 8.1 Core which can't be connected to a domain.  Your question in your last comment is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use loopback policy mode.  After the standard computer policy is applied, then the standard user policy is applied, loopback applies ANOTHER generic user policy on top of that that is defined on the computer level.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231287

This lets you supply a "generic" user policy on the computer level that is applied no matter what user logs in.

Comment: It says that the client must be running:                                                                                                             Windows XP Professional
Windows 2000 Professional
Windows 2000 Server
Windows 2000 Advanced Server
Windows Server 2003

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't catch that you weren't using the Pro version of windows.  I think that's going to be tough to do what you want to do without Pro.  I can't think of a way, sorry.